# Coordinates of mouse points in case of Multiple monitor application

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a application which can be run on multiple monitors. Now I want if multiple monitors are open then on mouse click how could I know on which monitor and which coordinate that current mouse point is pointing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mouse.Capture(Application.Current.MainWindow);
                var mousePointerPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
                Application.Current.MainWindow.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                Screen targetScreen = null;
                if (Application.Current.MainWindow.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    var pointAbs = Application.Current.MainWindow.PointToScreen(mousePointerPosition);

                    foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
                    {
                        if (screen.Bounds.Contains(new System.Drawing.Point((int)pointAbs.X, (int)pointAbs.Y)))
                        {
                            targetScreen = screen;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
if (targetScreen != null)
                {
                    var targetX = (targetScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2) + targetScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
                    var targetY = (targetScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2) + targetScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
                    //now here you can use this value as current mouse point in case of multiple monitors
                }
```